# Saving a UNIX timestamp in MySQL as type DOUBLE?

Tags: mysql, types, timestamp, double, int

My function call takes some input, and throws it into a database. Usually, it's integers, but today, I need it to throw in a unix timestamp.

This overflew the FLOAT type, but works with type DOUBLE.

Is there anything I should be worried about by saving that 10-digit integer in type DOUBLE?

Comment: I did found a strange error, posted here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503646/mysql-double-type-comparation-fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total precision of a [DOUBLE PRECISION](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) value is approximately 16 decimal digits, so you should not worry, even if you store milliseconds or microseconds.

Comment: Cheersh! So float, then, would be 8 digits, I assume?

Comment: for a 32 bit floating point, 24 bits of significand precision, log10(2^24) ≈ 7.225 decimal digits