# MySQL double type comparation fails

Tags: mysql

I am developing a chat module with JavaScript and php+mysql and I am storing the chat data into a simple table with: `id, member1, member2, message, timestamp`.
The `timestamp` column is **double(14,4)**, where I store the timestamp on microseconds level, ex:
1330522898.3137;

My problem is: 
When I am comparing this timestamp with another one, like

```
   SELECT * FROM chat_rows WHERE timestamp >= 1330535168.9548
```

Only on particular numbers, like this one above, I get 0 rows using operator `>=` although I have a row with exact same value; This is proved by the almost same query differentiated by operator `=` :

```
   SELECT * FROM chat_rows WHERE timestamp = 1330535168.9548
```

which returns one row;

The workaround for this is to replace the double(14,4) type with varchar but is slower than double;

Also fails only on this server ( my development one ):
Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
MySQL client version: 5.1.58

On my local it seems that works; - which is windows
Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8o
Versiunea clientului MySQL: mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 318113 $

Any thoughts ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you use `decimal(14,4)`?

Comment: If you cast it to a string, then compare the strings, it should work. The problem is that the 14,4 is the display size, but the value and the comparison go beyond that. The alternative is to use decimal.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it really  worked; I still did not understood why this is happening, if I have 14,4 double values stored and I am comparing to the same number, why should the comparison go beyond ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do floating-point number comparison is to first decide on an acceptable tolerance for differences between the numbers and then do the comparison against the tolerance value.

[MySQL floating point comparison issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567434/mysql-floating-point-comparison-issues)